# Estimate the gradient of an undefined surface

Tags: r, surface, raster, terrain, gradient

I want to estimate the gradient (slope and aspect) of an *undefined* surface (i.e., the function is unknown). To test my methods, here is the test data:

```
require(raster); require(rasterVis)            
set.seed(123)
x <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
y <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)
e <- 0.5 * rnorm(100)
test <- expand.grid(sort(x),sort(y))
names(test)<-c('X','Y')
z1 <- (5 * test$X^3 + sin(3*pi*test$Y))
realy <- matrix(z1, 100, 100, byrow = F)
# And a few plots for demonstration #
persp(sort(x), sort(y), realy, 
      xlab = 'X', ylab = "Y", zlab = 'Z',
      main = 'Real function (3d)', theta = 30, 
      phi = 30, ticktype = "simple", cex=1.4)
      contour(sort(x), sort(y), realy, 
      xlab = 'X', ylab = "Y",
      main = 'Real function (contours)', cex=1.4)
```

I convert everything into a raster and plot using `rasterVis::vectorplot`. Everything looks fine. The vector field indicates the direction of the highest magnitude of change and the shading is similar to my contour plot...

```
test.rast <- raster(t(realy), xmn = 0, xmx = 1, 
                    ymn = 0, ymx = 1, crs = CRS("+proj"))
vectorplot(test.rast, par.settings=RdBuTheme, narrow = 100, reverse = T)
```

However, I need a matrix of slope values. As I understand vectorplot, it uses the raster::terrain function:

```
terr.mast <- list("slope" = matrix(nrow = 100, 
                                   ncol = 100, 
                                   terrain(test.rast, 
                                           opt = "slope", 
                                           unit = "degrees",
                                           reverse = TRUE, 
                                           neighbors = 8)@data@values, 
                                    byrow = T),
                  "aspect" = matrix(nrow = 100, 
                                    ncol = 100, 
                                    terrain(test.rast, 
                                            opt = "aspect", 
                                            unit = "degrees",
                                            reverse = TRUE, 
                                            neighbors = 8)@data@values, 
                                     byrow = T))
```

however, the slope seem really high... ( 90 degrees would be vertical, right?!)

```
terr.mast$slope[2:6,2:6] 
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
#[1,] 87.96546 87.96546 87.96546 87.96550 87.96551
#[2,] 84.68628 84.68628 84.68627 84.68702 84.68709
#[3,] 84.41349 84.41350 84.41349 84.41436 84.41444
#[4,] 84.71757 84.71757 84.71756 84.71830 84.71837
#[5,] 79.48740 79.48741 79.48735 79.49315 79.49367
```

and if I plot the slope and aspect, they don't seem to agree with the vectorplot graphic.

```
plot(terrain(test.rast, opt = c("slope", "aspect"), unit = "degrees", 
     reverse = TRUE, neighbors = 8))
```

My thoughts:

1. Vectorplot must be smoothing the slope, but how?
2. I am fairly certain that `raster::terrain` is using a roving-window method to calculate slope. Perhaps the window is too small... can this be expanded?
3. Am I going about this in an inappropriate fashion? How else might I estimate the slope of an undefined surface?

Comment: The unit in the data slot of that object is not "degrees", it is "". Furthermore, test.rast is NOT an S3 object and returns an error with `test.rast$slope`. I see you have spelled 'terr.mast'. Do you have some other objects banging around???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I build a `RasterLayer` with your data using functions from `raster`:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

test.rast <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100, xmn = 0, xmx = 1,  ymn = 0, ymx = 1)
xy <- xyFromCell(test.rast, 1:ncell(test.rast))
test.rast[] <- 5*xy[,1] + sin(3*pi*xy[,2])
```

Let's display this object with `levelplot`:

```
levelplot(test.rast)
```

[image: levelplot]

and the gradient vector field with `vectorplot`:

```
vectorplot(test.rast)
```

[image: vectorplot]

If you only need the slope you get it with `terrain`:

```
slope <- terrain(test.rast, unit='degrees')

levelplot(slope, par.settings=BTCTheme())
```

[image: slope]

However, if I understand you right, you really need the gradient, so
you should compute both the slope and the aspect:

```
sa <- terrain(test.rast, opt=c('slope', 'aspect'))
```

In order to understand the way `vectorplot` is drawing the arrows,
here I show the part of its (modified) code where the horizontal
and vertical components of the arrows are calculated:

```
dXY <- overlay(sa, fun=function(slope, aspect, ...){
    dx <- slope*sin(aspect) ##sin due to the angular definition of aspect
    dy <- slope*cos(aspect)
    c(dx, dy)
    })
```

Because of the structure of the original `RasterLayer`, the
horizontal component is almost constant, so let's draw our
attention on the vertical component. The next code overlays the
arrows of the vector field over this vertical component.

```
levelplot(dXY, layers=2, par.settings=RdBuTheme()) +
    vectorplot(test.rast, region=FALSE)
```

[image: dY]

Finally, if you need the values of the slope and aspect use
`getValues`:

```
saVals <- getValues(sa)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Oscar. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `imager` functions for this:

```
library(imager)

# view (plot) image matrix
image(realy)

# compute gradient
gradient <- imgradient(as.cimg(realy), "xy")

# view x and y gradients
plot(gradient$x)
plot(gradient$y)

# access matrix values
mat.x <- as.matrix(gradient$x)
mat.y <- as.matrix(gradient$y)
```