# calculate and plot vector field of an arbitrary rasterLayer

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-raster

## Problem statement:

With `ggquiver::geom_quiver()` we can plot vector fields, provided we know `x`, `y`, `xend`, and `yend`.

1. How can I calculate these parameters for an arbitrary `RasterLayer` of elevations?
2. How can I ensure that the size of these arrows indicates the slope for that particular vector such that the arrows appear different lengths proportional to the gradient at that location (e.g., the first plot below)?

---

## Background:

```
# ggquiver example

library(tidyverse)
library(ggquiver)
expand.grid(x=seq(0,pi,pi/12), y=seq(0,pi,pi/12)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,u=cos(x),v=sin(y))) +
  geom_quiver()
```

[image]

A related appraoch uses `rasterVis::vectorplot`, which relies on `raster::terrain` (provided the field units == CRS units) to calculate and plot a vector field. [Source code is here](https://github.com/oscarperpinan/rastervis/blob/master/R/vectorplot.R).

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
r <- getData('alt', country='FRA', mask=TRUE)
r <- aggregate(r, 20)
vectorplot(r, par.settings=RdBuTheme())
```

[image]

---

## Conclusion:

To review, I'd like to take an arbitrary `rasterLayer` of elevation, convert it to a `data.frame`, calculate the `x`, `y`, `xmax`, and `ymax` components of an elevation vector field that size the arrows such that they show the relative slope at the point (as in plots 1 and 2 above), and plot with `ggquiver`. Something like:

```
names(r) <- "z"
rd <- as.data.frame(r, xy=TRUE)

# calculate x, y, xend, yend for gradient vectors, add to rd, then plot

ggplot(rd) + 
  geom_raster(aes(x, y, fill = z)) + 
  geom_quiver(aes(x, y, xend, yend))
```

Comment: Why arbitrary, isn't the size slope normalized by raster cell size oriented in aspect direction. This is then distance and bearing from the center of each cell. see geosphere pkg.

Comment: I think this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16371769

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Effectively what you're asking is to convert a 2D [scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field) into a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field). There are a few different ways to do this.

The raster package contains the function `terrain`, which creates new raster layers that will give you both the angle of your desired vector at each point (i.e. the *aspect*), and its magnitude (the *slope*). We can use a little trigonometry to convert these into the North-South and East-West basis vectors used by `ggquiver` and add them to our original raster before turning the whole thing into a data frame.*

```
terrain_raster <- terrain(r, opt = c('slope', 'aspect'))
r$u <- terrain_raster$slope[] * sin(terrain_raster$aspect[])
r$v <- terr$slope[] * cos(terr$aspect[])
rd <- as.data.frame(r, xy = TRUE)
```

However, in most cases this will not make for a good plot. If you don't first aggregate the raster, you will have one gradient for each pixel on the image, which won't plot well. On the other hand, if you *do* aggregate, you will have a nice vector field, but your raster will look "blocky". Therefore, having a single data frame for your plot is probably not the best way to go.

The following function will take a raster and plot it with an overlaid vector field. You can adjust how much the vector field is aggregated without affecting the raster, and you can specify an arbitrary vector of colours for your raster.

```
raster2quiver <- function(rast, aggregate = 50, colours = terrain.colors(6))
{
  names(rast) <- "z"
  quiv <- aggregate(rast, aggregate)
  terr <- terrain(quiv, opt = c('slope', 'aspect'))
  quiv$u <- terr$slope[] * sin(terr$aspect[])
  quiv$v <- terr$slope[] * cos(terr$aspect[])
  quiv_df <- as.data.frame(quiv, xy = TRUE)
  rast_df <- as.data.frame(rast, xy = TRUE)

  print(ggplot(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + 
          geom_raster(data = rast_df, na.rm = TRUE) + 
          geom_quiver(data = quiv_df, aes(u = u, v = v), vecsize = 1.5) +
          scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colours, na.value = "transparent") +
          theme_bw())

  return(quiv_df)
}
```

So, trying it out on your France example, after first defining a similar colour palette, we get

```
pal <- c("#B2182B", "#E68469", "#D9E9F1", "#ACD2E5", "#539DC8", "#3C8ABE", "#2E78B5")

raster2quiver(getData('alt', country = 'FRA', mask = TRUE), colours = pal)
```

[image]

Now to show that it works on an *arbitrary* raster (provided it has a projection assigned) let's test it out on this image, as converted to a raster. This time, we have a lower resolution so we choose a smaller aggregate value. We'll also choose a transparent colour for the lowest values to give a nicer plot:

[image]

```
rast <- raster::raster("https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXUXO.png")

# Add a fake arbitrary projection otherwise "terrain()" doesn't work:
projection(rast) <- "+proj=lcc +lat_1=48 +lat_2=33 +lon_0=-100 +ellps=WGS84"

raster2quiver(rast, aggregate = 20, colours = c("#FFFFFF00", "red"))
```

[image]

*  <sub>*I should point out that `geom_quiver`'s mapping aesthetic takes arguments called `u` and `v`, which represent the basis vectors pointing North and East. The `ggquiver` package converts them to `xend` and `yend` values using `stat_quiver`. If you prefer to use `xend` and `yend` values you could just use `geom_segment` to plot your vector field, but this makes it more complex to control the appearance of the arrows. Hence, this solution will find the magnitude of the `u` and `v` values instead.*</sub>